# Three.js transparency and canvas transparency are not the same

Tags: canvas, three.js

have troubles with using canvas in THREE.js. It should be transparent, such as material, but I still can see white rectangle like as on image.
There is a canvas, used for writting text on a plane.

```
    const can = document.createElement('canvas');
    can.width = 512;
    can.height = 256;
    const canvasTexture = new THREE.Texture( can );
```

I have a SpriteMaterial (legacy-code, I know) with these settings:

```
    const spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {
      map: canvasTexture,
      depthTest: false,
      depthWrite: false,
      transparent: true,
      color: 0xffffff,
    } );
```

I add the text to the canvas like

```
    const ctx = can.getContext( '2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.font = "96px Arial";
    ctx.fillText( text, 10, can.height * 0.8 );
```

And then re-apply canvas as material image.
But it looks like this

[image: this]

Thx for any help!

I've tried to add some opacity to material, changing values of depthTest, depthWrite, clearing canvas before adding text. I expect not to see white rect, but to see only text.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have made the object transparent without chageing the opacity. Opacity has a range between 0 - 1 and will default to 1 if not changed. Try the following:

```
const spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( {
  map: canvasTexture,
  depthTest: false,
  depthWrite: false,
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0.5,
  color: 0xffffff,
} );
```